# Column doesn't exist when using CASE expression in WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql

I have this SQL

```
SELECT 
    price_amount, 
    price_currency, 
    CASE 
        WHEN price_currency='USD' THEN price_amount * 3.9024 
        WHEN price_currency='EUR' THEN price_amount * 4.413 
        WHEN price_currency='ILS' THEN price_amount * 1 
        ELSE price_amount * 1 
    END AS final_price 
FROM items 
WHERE final_price BETWEEN 1 AND 100
```

but I get:

> ERROR:  column "final_price" does not exist
>   LINE 1: ...ce_amount * 1 END AS final_price FROM items WHERE final_pric...

It is getting selected using alias, so why is it trying to find it in the table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WHERE clause is evaluated **before** aliases in the `SELECT` clause. `WHERE` is used to locate rows from the base table which are the input to all expressions in the `SELECT`. Only after locating the rows your `CASE` can be evaluated with real values and the `final_price` alias is assigned its value.

There are multiple ways to solve that:

- repeat the same expression in the `WHERE` clause - that way it will be used to locate the rows
- wrap your query as a subquery in another query and move the `WHERE` to the outer query - as you select from a derived table, the alias becomes a "real" column that way
- <sub>(this would work in MySQL, **but not in** PostgreSQL) use the `HAVING` clause instead of WHERE - `HAVING` (in MySQL) works after the `SELECT` is computed to do a "second wave" of filtering. In standard SQL (and in Postgres), `SELECT` is logically processed after `HAVING`, so this won't work.</sub>
- create a generated/virtual column from your `CASE` expression, that way it becomes a part of your base table and you might even be able to index it

Warning: your query will need to do fulltable/index scan unless you can add some "simpler" `WHERE` conditions or be able to use the indexed virtual column.

Comment: To read more on the subject https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/07/logical-query-processing/ (no affiliation! 2nd time posting this link in 2minutes)